# Why Laravel Vite Directive Not Working in My Project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, vite

I installed and configured laravel breeze and blade according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-blade) given by laravel. By default it uses Vite but somehow @vite directive is not working in my project and I don't know what I miss.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
};
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ]
});
```

The vite is compiling properly my js and css assets:
[image]

I then created a test blade template with `@vite` directive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

<!-- Scripts -->
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>
<body>
<div class="font-sans text-gray-900 antialiased">
    Hello World
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My test route:

```
Route::get('/nice', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

The output below shows that the `@vite` is not generating the appropriate script and link assets tag:

[image]

My development environment is homestead, and I have laravel mix alongside since I am slowly upgrading our front-end to vite. I hope somebody here will be able to help me fix the issues and thank you.

Comment: Do other Blade functions work in that template, like `{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}` in the title?

Comment: @brombeer Yes the other functions are working.

Comment: This is interesting, can you also show the code inside `package.json` too?

Comment: I seem to have the same issue, when running `npm run dev` everything works like a charm, but the generated assets after running `npm run build` are not being loaded in the browser. This results in pages being displayed without CSS or JS. My @vite directive is trying to fetch my files, but cannot map the correct locations as stated in the manifest.json. My setup is a fresh, out-of-the-box Laravel 9 installation, with the same setup as OP (with Breeze installed).

Comment: Hey ho, is there any fix yet? Im having the same issue.

Answer (score 29):

Laravel 8 documentation says to install the laravel breeze using the following command.

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
```

But this will install the latest version of breeze (^1.10) with Laravel 9 Vite support. As Laravel 8 doesn't support Vite, you will have to use an older version of laravel breeze. Version 1.9.4 works for me with Laravel 8.

So try the following command to install laravel breeze instead:

```
composer require laravel/breeze:1.9.4
```

Comment: Don't forget `php artisan breeze:install`

Comment: This is the correct answer for those using Laravel 8

Comment: how did you figure out it's Lv 8? Also this is kinda not helpful

Answer (score 11):

You must clear view cache after upgrade framework version with command:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Then this new blade directive must work properly.

Comment: I have done that as well and cleared all the cache, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to solve my own issue, I came up with a solution for your problem!

A fresh, out-of-the-box installation of Breeze makes use of a bunch of components. These can be found in the `resources/views/components` folder of your app. Per default, Breeze also comes with 2 layout components:

- `app/View/Components/AppLayout.php`
- `app/View/Components/GuestLayout.php`

The HTML structure of these layout components can be found in:

- `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`
- `resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php`

These layouts are used to wrap the contents of called view based on a user being logged in or not.

In your case, you try to visit the URL `/nice`, which returns the `test.blade.php` view. The view is rendered without any `<html>`, `<body>` or any other 'wrapping' html tags because there is no reference to any layout.

For example, let's say your `test.blade.php` can only be viewed by logged in users. Try changing `test.blade.php` file to:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Test') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="font-sans text-gray-900 antialiased">
        Hello World
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

By wrapping your content between the `x-app-layout` tags (for guest users the `x-guest-layout` tags), you basically say that Laravel should render the contents of your `test.blade.php` into the default slot of the `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` file.

The example code above also shows how you can populate slots of your `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` from inside your `test.blade.php`. The contents of the `<x-slot name="header">` tag is placed where `{{ $header }}` is stated, much like how a Collection is passed down from a controller to a view.

In the documentation (found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#building-layouts)) you can find how components work in Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me after clearing the application cache

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Refer to my blog post if you migrating mix to vite

https://balajidharma.medium.com/how-to-migrating-from-laravel-mix-to-vite-fbb912237844

Answer (score 1):

Laravel version must be `^9.19` to use Vite.

```
// composer.json

"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
},
```

Comment: I tried upgrading from 9.0 to 9.19, still not working :(

Comment: I'm trying to start a new L8... and vite and its directives are in there... not working. of course

Comment: `composer update` works to me (laravel/framework updated to 9.45), but after that you **need** to clear cache with `php artisan cache:clear` or/and `php artisan view:clear`

Answer (score 1):

In your `docker-composer.yml` file update the HMR ports to `'${HMR_PORT:-5173}:5173'`
or whatever port your vite dev server is serving your assets.

```
    laravel.test:
    build:
        context: ./docker/8.1
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        args:
            WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
    image: sail-8.1/app
    extra_hosts:
        - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    ports:
        - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        - '${HMR_PORT:-5173}:5173'
    environment:
        WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
        LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
    volumes:
        - '.:/var/www/html'
    networks:
        - sail
    depends_on:
        - mysql
        - redis
        - meilisearch
        - selenium
```

Comment: Hi thank your for responding. I am sorry I am not using docker yet my environment is currently homestead.

Comment: How can I see the port?

Comment: i have same issue, can you explain better?
My docker is set to work in https, i tried to set -5173:443 but it show me always 404

Answer (score 1):

I used this [Referecnce](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/vite-with-laravel/) to get my project working with vite.

[TLDR;](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/vite-with-laravel/)
In order to create a new Directive, you need to add your script to the Helper function to the `composer.json` file and add the it to `files` array. See example below

open `composer.json` which should be located in the `root` of your Laravel project find the section below:

```php
 "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "app/Helpers/functions.php" // this is where you can load your code
    ],
    "psr-4": {
     ...
    }
  },
```

Then in in the same root composer installed so you can run the following in your terminal

`composer autodump --optimize-autoloader` to initialise for use in the script

Answer (score 1):

Just go to config/app.php and:

```
 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
 // 'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', '/'),
 'asset_url' => env('APP_URL', '/'),
```

After, run

```
 php artisan config:clear
```

.env file may do not content ASSET_URL parameter. Just set ASSET_URL same to APP_URL

All 404 NOT FOUND errors can be tracked to an URL misconfiguration

Comment: This question is not about URL errors. It's about @vite directive not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

yesterday I was also facing same error and after googling too much I could not find any doable solution.
In my case I was using Laravel 8.83 and Breeze 1.10.2 for user registration and Auth with PHP 7.4. `php artisan install:breeze` command was failing again and again.

In my case I fixed it my using a lower version of breeze i.e. 1.9.4 after using this version of breeze `php artisan install:breeze` run successfully without any error and all other site functionality is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it drove me crazy for a few days.

But I came across a solution.

According to the guide below I needed to rename the "vite.config.js file" to "vite.config.mjs" then as per instructions I went to the package.json file and added this line:

```js
//Add this line in the very top/first object.

> "type": "module"
```

It should look like this on package.json with the new property 'type' and value 'module':

{
"name": "myapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"type": "module"
}

The solution came from the URL below:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#this-package-is-esm-only

Answer (score -2):

**@vite is for Laravel version 9*.**

```
you install Laravel 8 but you installed UI or other package maybe related to Laravel version 9.
so Please check your package version for Laravel 8 .
then install specific Version.
```